# AzureRM site-to-site Connections status is "Unknown"

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network

First, I followed the instruction [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps/) to create a point-to-site VPN. Then I created a site-to-site VPN to my local network on the portal UI. My on-premises VPN gateway device is Dell Sonicwall SOHO running SonicOS Enhanced 5.9.1.4-4o. The settings of the Sonicwall router is shown in [this document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0pjlQ4JEOiJdDZaaTA3TnIySjg).

I am able to connect to the VNet via P2S but I couldn't ping the VM. The site-to-site connection status shown is "Unknown" instead of "Connected" or "Not Connected". I tried to search for the meaning of "Unknown" status but I couldn't find any clue. Does anyone have any idea ?

Thanks,
CK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the ICMP protocol used by ping is turned off.  So you can’t ping your VM unless you allow the ICMP Protocol.
To test connectivity, you can do a port ping. While Ping.exe uses ICMP, other tools such as  PsPing, Nmap, or Telnet allow you to test connectivity to a specific TCP port.

Comment: Hi, Stephanie. I have the ICMP allowed on my firewall inbound rules and tried to disable the firewall but it doesn't resolve the issue. I think it is most likely due to the vnet or Azure RM network security group rules. Any idea ? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You can use Ping with Azure virtual machines if:
•You have a network connection, VPN or ExpressRoute, that bypasses the load balancer,  AND •The firewall in the guest OS of the Azure virtual machine allows inbound ICMP traffic. So you would also need to bypass the loadbalancer...or use another option. More info here https://www.petri.com/how-to-remotely-ping-microsoft-azure-vms. Can you please mark as solved if it answers the question ? Many thanks.